# What is the function of but in the sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, subordinate-clauses

> I don't know **why** **but** for some reason when I got on the train that
>   day it was unusually full, something I don't recall ever happening in
>   the past.

As for the above sentence, I have some questions:

1. Is why a conjunction or adverb? My own understanding is that *why* is an adverb here which modifies the verb *know*, and *but* is the conjunction which connects two clauses. Is that true?
2. As I read on [Grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-but/), when *but* is joining two independent clauses, we need to put a comma before it. Otherwise, leave the comma out. According to this rule, the two clauses are **'I don't know why'** and **'for some reason when I got on the train that day it was unusually full, something I don't recall ever happening in the past.'**  But since there is no comma and the second clause doesn't express a complete thought, the second clause is a dependent clause or subordinate clause. Is that right?
3. someone told me that the whole sentence is an object clause after *why*, but if the above clues are correct, then the sentence is not a object clause.

Comment: I think *... the train it that day it was ...* has one extra *it*. A typo, perhaps?

Comment: I think there should be a comma between 'why' and 'but'... That will make matters more meaningful. There could have been a mistake when this was written, because the "I don't know why" clause is almost always followed by a comma.

Comment: Also, the second clause is an independent idea... The sentence 'For some reason when I got on the train that day it was unusually full, something I don't recall ever happening in the past' sounds fine as an independent sentence.

Comment: Personally, that sentence wants a comma between why and but.

Answer (score 2):

The general form "I don't know [question word], but" is a common idiomatic expression.  The overall *intent* is to indicate some measure of *surprise* at an unexpected or unusual situation.

> *I don't know how, but* the cat got on top of the roof and now she can't get down.
>
> *I don't know why, but* the mayor thought it was a good idea to hold a press conference during a thunderstorm.
>
> *I don't know exactly who, but* somebody ate all the chocolate cake I had been saving.
>
> *I don't know when, but* some time recently the clocks were all reset.

And so on.  I would memorize and practice it like any other idiomatic expression, as a complete phrase, since the individual words are not as important.